# Multiple users' data with single Twitter API request

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to build a script that will take a Twitter handle and calculate its engagement rate based on the last 10 tweets or so. If I understand Twitter's API correctly I would have to make a q request for each calculation. If I understand Twitter's pricing correctly, I would be paying between $0.75 and $1 per request depending on my package. That seems very expensive for me to build such a simple tool. Am I missing something, is there a cheaper way of doing it?

Comment: Why not just use the standard (no cost) user timeline API to retrieve a user’s last 200 Tweets, and look at the most recent 10 of those for likes and retweets?

Comment: Isn't that limited to like 100 requests/month? @AndyPiper

Comment: I think you're confusing the standard APIs with the premium API sandbox.
The standard user timeline API endpoint allows 1500 requests every 15 minutes (app only auth) or 900 requests every 15 minutes (user auth). That should be more than enough for your use case.